# Pandas: Insert a missing weekday (not based on dates) and populate it with zeros

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a dataframe as follows and I am trying to insert the missing weekday and populate the corresponding bin values to zeros.

[image]

Problem is I am not working with dates as such, so I don't have the date information apart from this table.

***My code:***

```
pivoted = df.pivot(index=['id', 'day_of_week'], columns='bin', values='freq')
pivoted = pivoted.fillna(0)
```

I am trying to add **'Monday'** and set the corresponding bins to zeros but wondering how to proceed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have used pivot on the dataframe if I am not wrong. Can you share the dataframe for reference to see what exactly is the pivot performing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex your output to add back any missing days and at the same time sort the days too.

It looks like the output of your pivot table yields a multi-index, so we'll need to use [pd.MultiIndex.from_product](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

```
pivoted.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
                    pivoted.index.levels[0],
                    ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']]), 
                fill_value=0)
```